# Decommissioned node appearing in nodetool gossipinfo with status LEFT

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.2

We decommissioned a node and after it's complete, we noticed that node was not showing up in "nodetool status", "nodetool ring" and "system.peers" table but it showing up in "nodetool describecluster" in UNREACHABLE and in "nodetool gossipinfo" with status as LEFT. So i did rolling restart of my cluster. After that decommissioned node IP didn't show up in "nodetool describecluster" output but still showing up in "nodetool gossipinfo" output.

Now i want to clean the decommissioned node and add it to the new different cluster, can i do that? with that decommissioned node showing up in old clusters "nodetool gossipinfo" output still?

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your decommissioned node and add it to the new cluster, there won't be any problem. I did it several times before. Just make sure that you've cleaned all the data and commitlog from the node before joining to the new cluster.

And also, successfully decommissioned node never shown up in `nodetool status`,`nodetool ring`.